# Table View Cell Image Stretching in ipad

Tags: iphone, image, ipad, uitableview

I am setting the `background image` for `UITableViewCell` it is working fine but it stretches the image i do not want to stretch the image and i want the image should be of same size in cell so i think cell size should be same

here is the code for cell image

```
cell.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0]]autorelease];
```

My image size is "275 (width) * 59 (height)".

Any idea how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UIImageView *imgV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
imgV.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
cell.backgroundView = imgV;
```

AspectFit and some more modes are there. I am not sure whether it will work for cell back groundView. Just give a try.

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom cell of UITableView and set the frame of UIImageView exactly to the dimension of the image that is in your case width is 275 and height is 59 so set the frame of UIImageView according to your image height and width image will not stretch.

Comment: and what to give the custom cell width and height

Comment: It depends upon your requirement if you want to show the image in whole area of the custom cell then set the frame of custom cell equal to the UIImageView frame or else give the height of the custom cell equal to image height and width of the custom cell will be width of your screen.

Comment: can you please tell me the UITableView used in splitView controller for root view controller what is the tableView widht so that i may give frame size custom according to that

Comment: For SplitViewController the frame of UITableViewController  i dont know but you do a trail by guessing the frame set some frame to custom if it didn't fit accordingly adjust the frame of the custom cell do this until you get the exact frame.